# How to run shell command inside pod container using kubectl having double pipes?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, jvm, exec, kubectl

This command works perfectly fine which gives the JVM native memory summary.
`jcmd  $(jps | awk '/jar/ || /Bootstrap/ || /java/ {print $1}') VM.native_memory summary`
I want to run this command inside the container using `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- jcmd  $(jps | awk '/jar/ || /Bootstrap/ || /java/ {print $1}') VM.native_memory summary`
Unfortunately, this fails as **Could not find any processes matching : 'VM.native_memory'
command terminated with exit code 1**
My purpose is to run this command using a php script which will be called by another using URL and puts the returned data into the same page.
Please help how can I achieve that?

Comment: I just put the command into a script, copied into pod and invoked. That way it works without any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- jcmd  $(jps | awk '/jar/ || /Bootstrap/ || /java/ {print $1}') VM.native_memory summary Unfortunately, this fails as Could not find any processes matching : 'VM.native_memory' command terminated with exit code 1
```

The above command got executed properly inside pod, as it didn't find any process matching native memory hence it has exited with that message.  Also you can ensure the native memory is properly enabled please refer [java official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html#enable_nmt)

Comment: No!
The issue is with pipe after jps i.e. ```jps | ```. The same command would work inside the container but won't work when called using the ```kubectl exec```.
I had done some heck to do this. i.) put the same command in the script.sh ii.) copy the script inside the pod/container iii.) call the script.sh using ```kubectl exec```